# "removedialog" issue when displaying 2 dialogs at the same time

Tags: java, android, dialog

In the method "OnCreate" of my actvity, I'm displaying a little progress dialog while loading data. It's done every time the "OnCreate" method is called so even when the screen orientation change.$

In the nominal case, there is no problem even if the user change the screen orientation.

But, if the user opens another dialog (used to select an item in a list), then change the orientation, the progress dialog is displayed behind the "list" dialog and is not impacted by the "removeDialog".

Do you have any clues on that behavior ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

call "removeDialog" or "dismissDialog" before "startDialog" with try-catch and so on. You can call "removeDialog" or "dismissDialog" several times...